# Правильно ли я понимаю инкапсуляцию и понятия объекта?

Tags: java, c#, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, uml

*инкапсуляция - когда внутреннее состояние объектов может изменяться только самим объектом (способность объекта сохранять свое внутреннее состояние).*

Что есть объект:

Это сущность который одновременно содержащая в себе поведения и данные. Физический этот сущность располагается в адресном пространстве компьютера(тоже в одном месте в памяти).

Объекта есть признаки такие как атрибуты, состояния, поведения.

Объектом может рассматривается класс, группа классов, подсистема.

Что есть состояния объекта:

Например если человек покрасил волосы то его состояния изменился т.к. свойство цвет волос поменял значения.

Пример:
Есть некая абстрактная мозг который может принимать информацию в линейно.

1) Этап скрытия данных

```
class Brain{

    String capsule;
}
```

Мы уже скрыли данные создав класс Brain. Теперь ему можно обратиться только создав инстанс этого класса. Другие способы достучаться до capsule нет. Таким образом внутреннее состояния Brain может изменить только объект этого класса.

Мы скрываем данные создав класс Brain от внешнего мира. Рас атрибуты скрыты от внешнего мира его внутреннее состоянию может менять только сам объект.

```
brain1 = new Brain();
brain2 = new Brain();

brain1.capsule = "Чайник";
brain2.capsule = "Магазин";
```

2) Этап скрыт детали реализации

```
class Brain{

    private String capsule;

    //Интерфейс методы для взаимодействия с объектом.(Слово интерфейс в широком понимании)
    public String getCapsule(){
        return capsule;
    }

    public void setCapsule(String data){

        if(!isBusy){
            //проверям является ли этот информация корректным
            //если да то проверям может ли мозг принят его
            if(isCorrect(data) && isAccept(data))
                capsule = data;
        }else{
            waitPleas();
        }
    }

    //Реализация
    private boolean isCorrect(String data){


    }

    //Реализация
    private boolean isAccept(String data){

    }

    private boolaen isBusy(){

    }
}
```

Классе Brain ограничили доступ к данным и скрыли детали реализации. Клиенту дали только интерфейс методы.

Comment: _brain1.capsule = "Чайник";_ - но здесь же значение поля устанавливается извне, а не самим объектом

Comment: Объект - это область памяти, в которой хранятся методы класса, в экземпляре - поля. При повторном выделении памяти создается экземпляр, но объект не создается. Инкапсуляция - скрытие реализации.

Comment: Данном контексте класс Brain рассмотрим как объект. а brain1 это экземпляр. Т.е.когда brain1 устанавливает значения capsule, то это для объекта Brain будет изменения состояния из вне ? Я думал что brain1 не должень изменять состояния brain2)

Comment: @АлександрПузанов объект - это и есть экземпляр. А вы путаете объект и класс.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, боюсь раздуть холивар по ооп, но Вы говорите про "практическое понимание" инкапсуляции в распространенных языках. В литературе по cs мне неоднократно попадалось определение инкапсуляции примерно как "объединение в одной сущности данных и методов работы с ними". То есть не сокрытие важно, а то что мы свойства и поведение мешаем.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Объектом может рассматривается класс, группа классов, подсистема. А конкретном реализации конечно есть Класс и экземпляр класса, (объект, инстанс). Называния то несколько. Я имеел ввиду слово объект в ширком смысле а не как инстанс класса(экзампляр класса)

Comment: На самом деле так и есть. Я высказал мнение на основании практического понимания.

Comment: Объект и экземпляр - это разные понятия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что касается объекта, вы сами ответили на свой вопрос в одном предложении (со слегка поломанной грамматикой, но понятно):

> Это сущность который одновременно содержащая в себе поведения и данные.

**Всё**. Всё остальное, что вы перечислили, это уже нерелевантные или даже ошибочные детали.

> Что есть состояния объекта

Определения вы так и не привели, вы сразу привели пример, не описывающий, что всё-таки такое **состояние**. А ответ очень прост. Это **данные** из определения объекта, данного вами же.

> Мы уже скрыли данные создав класс Brain. Теперь ему можно обратиться только создав инстанс этого класса. Другие способы достучаться до capsule нет.

Класс похож на "проект" для объектов, по которому можно создавать объекты, обладающие определёнными общими чертами. В вашем примере `capsule` является **частью** объектов класса `Brain`, и достучаться до `capsule` не имея объекта класса `Brain` невозможно не из-за сокрытия, а из-за того, что **`capsule` попросту нигде не существует**. `capsule` собственный у каждого объекта, и если объектов нет, то и `capsule` нет.

> Объектом может рассматривается класс, группа классов, подсистема.

Может. И не только это. Это примеры, не определения.

Разве что из вышесказанного вы можете задуматься, можно ли считать *класс* объектом. В контексте данного выше определения *обычно можно.* В современных языках программирования часто встречается возможность определения именно **у класса** полей и поведения. А где-то даже семантика языка прямо это утверждает ([`Class.new.is_a?(Object) # => true` в Ruby](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584323/181100)).

Но это общее понятие объекта. В конкретном языке же оно может отличаться. В С++, например, объектами принято называть экземпляры классов и структур, они являются полноценными значениями, их можно передавать в функции и возвращать их оттуда. Классы в С++ с этой точки зрения объектами не являются.

---

Идея же **инкапсуляции** в том, чтобы разделять **пользователя** и **разработчика**, из предположения, что **пользователь** не может изменять определение объекта (чаще косвенно, путём изменения определения *класса*, к которому объект относится), а **разработчик** может.

Делается это путём **сокрытия для внешнего осмотра тех деталей класса, которые пользователю видеть необязательно**. Изнутри же (из предположения выше, что внутри бывает только разработчик) все детали по-прежнему видны.

В основном это **"фильтр от лишнего шума"**. Сделав нечто приватным, разработчик говорит нечто вроде *"вам всё равно это не потребуется при штатном использовании"*. Если бы сокрытия не существовало, разработчик был бы вынужден как-то отметить часть доступного содержимого объекта как "детали реализации" в документации.

Почему-то многие считают, что инкапсуляция это запрет, вроде таблички *"руками не трогать"* в каком-нибудь музее. Что она **защищает объект от посягательств недобросовестных пользователей**. Она действительно выполняет и эту задачу. Если бы сокрытия не было, у пользователя могло бы быть больше возможностей документацию нарушить и получить объект в некорректном состоянии, что может закончиться чем угодно.

Но предотвращение ряда таких проблем это скорее приятный бонус, чем реальное назначение: в конце концов, где-то можно просто отредактировать класс, чтобы влезть в поля, которые разработчик не задумывал как общедоступные, где-то можно вскрыть интересующие места <s>ломиком</s> рефлексией.